# Tool for application code quality for PHP version 7.1

Tags: php, sonarqube, static-code-analysis

I just want to know that Is there any open source tool for code quality for PHP version 7.1 ? I've tried sonar but not happy with that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Variable sometimes this can be helpful for someone.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you were not satisfied with SonarPhp? Write us at https://community.sonarsource.com/ and maybe we can fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

There are various tools that can help you with your problem. but it depends on use case if you want to do static code analysis or find run time errors or optimisation faults.

here are a few
1) PHPCS (PHP CodeSniffer)
2) PHPMD (PHP Mess Detector)
3) PHPStan (PHP Static Analysis Tool)

refer https://web-techno.net/code-quality-check-tools-php/ for more detailed documentation and usage